# How to build a java factory using keys

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I am trying to build a command parser which receives a block of data and parses that data into an instance of a specific command. This is basically then a factory whereby the instance returned from the factory is based on a key.

So more specifically, say a receive a block of raw binary data:

0x02 0x23 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x1f

And the 3rd byte in this stream defines the command, I want to create an instance of CommandOne. Obviously there will be additional methods to handle parsing the rest of the data according to the command, but the first step is getting that instance of the command from the command number. This where I say this is a factory using a key.

There are a lot of discussions on how to build factories in java, some very direct, some using various bits of generics and reflections; but I have had no luck finding a specific implementation that fits what I am trying to accomplish. I did however find bits and pieces that relate to what I am trying to accomplish and so I have put those together into an answer which is the first response below. Is this a good response or am I overlooking something simpler or something more complete?

Comment: Well, now I am trying to figure out how this thing lets me answer my own question....

Comment: Which example are you talking about?

Comment: And put some code in the question, so that it is easier for us to follow!

Comment: You haven't posted your code yet, but it sounds like this is too broad, as you are requesting a code review. You may instead consider posting to [codereview.se], but first check with their help center.

Comment: I am afraid this is only going to offer opinions. Please see how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ideally, you should put the answer to your own question into the post before you submit the question (there's a check-box for "Answer your own question" on the ask page).

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to this site. I really am look for a response and so I have edited my question to make it more clear. This may also be a code review if no one has a better way of accomplishing what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a generic form of the solution. This is all built into a single package containing all the commands and the factory. Note that adding a new command does not require any changes to the factory itself.

This is the abstract class which all commands must implement. It also contains the factory method *getInstance*.

```
public abstract class Commands
{
  private static Map<Integer,Constructor<?>> commandConstructorMap = null;

  private static void loadMap()
  {
    commandConstructorMap = new HashMap<Integer,Constructor<?>>();
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if(classLoader == null) return;
    String myPathName = Commands.class.getName();
    String myPath[] = myPathName.split("\\.");
    if(myPath == null || myPath.length <= 1) return;
    int pkgLen = myPath.length - 1;
    StringBuilder pkgNm = new StringBuilder();
    pkgNm.append(myPath[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<pkgLen;i++)
      pkgNm.append(".").append(myPath[i]);
    String packageName = pkgNm.toString();
    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    Enumeration<URL> resources;
    try
    {
      resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      return; // failure, just leave constructor empty
    }
    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    while(resources.hasMoreElements())
      dirs.add(new File(resources.nextElement().getFile()));
    for(File dir:dirs)
    {
      if(!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) continue;
      File[] files = dir.listFiles();
      for(File file:files)
      {
        if(!file.isFile()) continue;
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if(!fileName.endsWith(".class")) continue;
        try
        {
          String className = packageName+'.'+fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-6);
          Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
          Constructor<?> cons = clazz.getConstructor();
          Object instance = cons.newInstance();
          if(instance instanceof Commands)
          {
            commandConstructorMap.put(new Integer(((Commands) instance).getCommand()),cons);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e){} // do nothing special for exception, just don't add to map
      }        
    }
  }
  
  
  public static Commands getInstance(Integer command) throws Exception
  {
    if(commandConstructorMap == null)
    {
      loadMap();
    }
    if(commandConstructorMap.containsKey(command))
      return (Commands)commandConstructorMap.get(cmd).newInstance();
    throw new Exception();
  }
  
  abstract Integer getCommand();
}
```

Note the return type of the abstracted *getCommand* is the same as the type used as the key, this is the relationship conrtol and can be almost any desired object type. One caveat of this mechanism is that this does create and ultimately discard one instance of every command object, but it does this only once, future calls will only create a single instance of the class indicated by the key.

This is an example of one of the command file implementations, obviously there would need to be other code related to building all the specifics of that command, the goal here is just to demonstrate how to build the part of the command class that is utilized in the factory.

```
public class CommandOne
    extends Commands
{
  Integer getCommand()
  {
    return new Integer(1);
  }
}
```

And finally a demonstration of how this works

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  try
  {
    Commands cmd = Commands.getInstance(new Integer(1));
    if(cmd instanceof CommandOne)
      System.out.println("Command using key 1 is: "+cmd.getClass().getSimpleName());
    cmd = Commands.getInstance(new Integer(2));
    if(cmd instanceof CommandTwo)
      System.out.println("Command using key 2 is: "+cmd.getClass().getSimpleName());
    cmd = Commands.getInstance(new Integer(3));
    if(cmd instanceof CommandThree)
      System.out.println("Command using key 3 is: "+cmd.getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Command instantiation failed");
  }
}
```

The results of running this (assuming there are definitions for commands CommandTwo and CommandThree as well as the demonstrated CommandOne) would be something like this:

> Command using key 1 is: CommandOne
>
> Command using key 2 is: CommandTwo
>
> Command using key 3 is: CommandThree